# Why the property defined by Object.defineProperties() is not seen in Object.keys()?

Tags: javascript

```
let user = {
    name: "John",
    surname: "Smith"
};

Object.defineProperty(user, 'fullName', {
    value: 'J Smith'
});

for (const key in user)  // or Object.keys(user)
    alert(key);  // name, surname
```

Any reason that such properties are skipped when iterating the properties of an object?

Answer (score 0):

The default property descriptor used by `Object.defineProperty` for data values is:

```
{
  writable: false,
  enumerable: false,
}
```

And `for..in` only iterates over enumerable properties.

If you want to iterate over *all* properties, use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`:

```js
let user = {
    name: "John",
    surname: "Smith"
};

Object.defineProperty(user, 'fullName', {
    value: 'J Smith'
});

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(user).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(key);
});
```

Or use `enumerable: true`:

```js
let user = {
    name: "John",
    surname: "Smith"
};

Object.defineProperty(user, 'fullName', {
    value: 'J Smith',
    enumerable: true
});

for (const key in user) {
  console.log(key);
}
```